# What is the easiest way to download a file out of an ECS container to local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, download, amazon-ecs, scp

I need to do some heap dumps and it would be great to have an easy (and fast) way to get the files as seamless as possible.

Current way doing it is:

1. Create file
2. Optional: Upload SSH key to EC2 instance if not yet known(depending on security model used)
3. Open SSH session (not using ASM as it has some OsX flaws)
4. copy docker container file to EC2 instance
5. SCP the file to local machine
6. Cleanup

This seems overwhelming complex for getting a single file. Is there a more straight-forward way in doing it? As this is an on demand use case I'd be ok with manual AWS Console way or using tools to do it more convenient. THX

Comment: this is not a full solution - I just ran into this myself - but I noticed the ecs task instances do have /bin/tftp 

So thinking I could tftp the file to a ec2 machine it can reach.

Not 100% sure if you meant an ecs task instance or an ec2 instance tho

Comment: file from/to ECS container [=ECS task]. So TFTP worked out without upfront configuration needs?

Comment: actually it turned out we had the volumes mounted on a perma-ec2 node so I just used that.  so not sure about the tftp solution.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the easiest way, then you just execute the `cat /some/file/here` command instead of bash and sending the output to a file on your local machine. Then remove the initial aws cli message from the beginning of the local file, such as:

```
The Session Manager plugin was installed successfully. Use the AWS CLI to start a session.


Starting session with SessionId: ecs-execute-command-<some session id>
This session is encrypted using AWS KMS.
```

If it's a binary file, then save it as a txt file, remove the initial cli output mentioned above, and rename it with the binary extension. Example:

```
aws ecs execute-command --region <your region> --cluster <your cluster> --task <your task ID> --container <your container> --command "cat /tmp/reportBatch.zip" --interactive >> ~/reportBatch.txt
```

For this method, you only need access to your ECS instance and be allowed to run commands on it.

Comment: Thanks! This is not really a download and only get's you the content of the file, not the file itself. It still might be still very useful for others.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this solution (it's working for me)

1. Step 1

   - Go into the container using this command

     `aws ecs execute-command --region <your region> --cluster <your cluster> --task <your task ID> --container <your container> --command "/bin/sh" --interactive`
2. Step 2

   - create base64 for your zip file and save it into the file, like that

     `base64 file.zip >> out.txt`
   - then copy the content of file in your clipboard
3. Step 3

   - using this site to decode base64 https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file then you can download your zip file
   - or using this command to decode:

     `base64 --decode out.txt > file.zip`

I hope it will work for you, let me know.

Comment: An alternative to the clipboard in step 2 (may struggle with large files) is to instead transfer the base64 file using Krisztián's method e.g: `aws ecs execute-command --region REGION --cluster CLUSTER --task TASKID --container CONTAINERNAME --interactive --command "cat out.txt" >> ./local/path/out.txt`. Note though you must delete the first & last few lines of non-b64 command output from out.txt, before passing it to `base64 --decode`. Also if you are unfortunate enough to be on Windows locally, ensure the text file uses LF line endings otherwise `base64` rejects it!